# ExpressJS installing errors in OS X

Tags: macos, express

I've been working on this for a while and it's the simplest thing....I NEED to simply install express so I can move on and actually work. No matter what I do I get this same error and Express won't install:

```
~ npm install -g express
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/revjtanton/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/express
/Users/revjtanton/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib
└── express@4.14.0

npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/Users/revjtanton/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "express"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm v3.9.3
npm ERR! path /Users/revjtanton/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/express
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, access '/Users/revjtanton/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/express'
npm ERR! at Error (native)
npm ERR! { [Error: EACCES, access '/Users/revjtanton/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/express']
npm ERR! errno: -13,
npm ERR! code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! path: '/Users/revjtanton/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/express' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /Users/revjtanton/npm-debug.log
```

I've managed permissions, cleaned caches, tried installing with sudo (which doesn't produce an error...but I'm still not able to use express).

Comment: sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/revjtanton/.nvm fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the command with `sudo`:

```
sudo npm install -g express
```